# Segmentation Fault 11 Error Output

Tags: c, string, pointers, segmentation-fault

I am currently getting a segfault, and I just can't seem to figure out why...
I am making a code that concatenates string values:

```
char* concat(char** strs, unsigned int nstrs)
{
  char* newstring;
  int length = 0;
  int j;
  int charcount;
  int strcount;
  int k = 0;
  for (j = 0; j <= nstrs - 1; j++) {
    length = sizeof(strs[j]) + length;
  }
  newstring = malloc(length);
  for (strcount = 0; strcount <= nstrs - 1; strcount++) {
    for (charcount = 0; charcount <= strlen(strs[strcount]) - 1; charcount++)     {
      newstring[k] = strs[charcount][strcount];
      k++;
    }
  }
  return newstring;
```

And in my main function I have...

```
  char* introname[] = {"My", "name", "is", "Trill-o"};
  printf("%s\n", concat(introname, 4));
```

Comment: `sizeof` does not do what you think it does.

Comment: well doesn't it compute the amount of bytes? And isn't that what I want when trying to allocate memory in the heap to "newstring"?

Comment: It yields, at compile-time (except for an obscure corner case not present here), the size of the type of what you pass in. `strs` is a `char**`, so `strs[anything]` is a `char*`, and it's size is that of a pointer. To know the length of a string in C, use `strlen()` which will actually cound the characters up to the end of the string.

Answer (score 2):

in your code, you need to change

```
sizeof(strs[j])
```

to

```
strlen(strs[j])
```

Always remember, `sizeof` is not a function, it's an operator. It returns the size of the supplied *data type*. In yor code, `strs[j]` is of type `char *`, so `sizeof` will return a value equal to `sizeof(char *)`.

To get the *length* of the *string*, you have to use `strlen()`.

That said, please note, `strlen()` does not include the count for terminating null. So, you've to add space for one more byte while using `length` in `malloc()`, like

```
  newstring = malloc(length + 1);    // 1 more byte for storing the terminating null.
```

Also, you must check the return value of `malloc()` to ensure the success. In case if `malloc()` fails, it will return `NULL` and the subsequent usage of `newstring` will lead to UB.

As per the logical part, your code should read

```
 newstring[k] = strs[strcount][charcount];
```

and to properly terminate the *string*,

```
newstring[k] = '\0' ;
```

outside `for` loop.

Answer (score 1):

```
sizeof(strs[j])
```

in the function will give `sizeof(pointer)` not `sizeof(array)`
But since you have a string use `strlen(strs[j])` to get the length of the string.

Please make a note to allocate memory to the `\0` character also.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use sizeof to get the length of a string.

You need to use strlen.

```
 sizeof(strs[j]) ; // bad, will return the sizeof pointer which is 4 or 8 depending on the system
 strlen(strs[j]); // this is what you want.
```

Answer (score 0):

Also C strings are **null** terminated character arrays. Make sure the concatenated string has a \0 at the end. Here is a working version : [string concatenation](http://ideone.com/mMdcEK)

Note I also switched the indexes of the arrays. I suppose this is what you want.

```
newstring = malloc(length + 1); // for '\0' character
...
newstring[k] = strs[strcount][charcount];
...
newstring[length] = '\0' ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem is here:

```
    length = sizeof(strs[j]) + length;
```

`sizeof` does not give the required length of the string as it is a `char *`, not an array. What you want is `strlen(strs[j]))`.

Also, when you've done totalling the lengths, add one for the terminating `NUL` before you `malloc`.

Finally this:

```
  newstring[k] = strs[charcount][strcount];
```

should be

```
  newstring[k] = strs[strcount][charcount];
```